# CSV File Processing - SAS

Tags: csv, import, sas, export

I am pretty new to SAS programming and trying to find the most efficient way to my current ongoing initiative. Basically, I need to modify the existing .csv file stored on the SAS server and save it in my folder on the same server.

Modification required:

- keep .csv as format
- use "|" instead of "," as delimiter
- have the following output name: filename_YYYYMMDDhhmmss.csv
- keep only 4 variables from the original file
- rename some of the variables we keep

Here is the script I am currently using, but there are a few issues with it:

```
 PROC IMPORT OUT = libname.original_file (drop=var0)
              FILE = "/.../file_on_server.csv"
              DBMS = CSV
              REPLACE;
 RUN;


%PUT date_human = %SYSFUNC(PUTN(%sysevalf(%SYSFUNC(TODAY())-1), datetime20.));

proc export data = libname.original_file ( rename= ( var1=VAR11 var2=VAR22 Type=VAR33 )) 
        outfile = '/.../filename_&date_human..csv' label dbms=csv replace;
        delimiter='|';
run;
```

I also have an issue with the variable called "Type" when renaming it as it looks like there is a conflict with some of the system key words. Date format is not good either, and I was not able to find the exact format on the SAS forums, unfortunately.

Any advice on how to make this script more efficient is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with trying to actually read the data into a SAS dataset. Just process it and write it back out.  If the input structure is consistent then it is pretty simple.  Just read everything as character strings and output the columns that you want to keep.

Let's assume that the data has 12 columns and the last one of the four that want to keep is the 10th column.  So you only need to read in 10 of them.

First setup your input and output filenames in macro variables to make it easier to edit. You can use your logic for generating the filename for the new file.

```
%let infile=/.../file_on_server.csv;
%let outfile=/.../filename_&date_human..csv;
```

Then use a simple DATA _NULL_ step to read the data as character strings and write it back out.  You can even change the relative order of the four columns if you want.  So this program will copy the 2nd, 5th, 4th and 10th columns and change the column headers to NewName1, NewName2, NewName3 and NewName4.

```
data _null_;
  infile "&infile" dsd dlm=',' truncover;
  file "&outfile" dsd dlm='|';
  length var1-var10 $200 ;
  input var1-var10;
  if _n_=1 then do;
     var2='NewName1';
     var5='NewName2';
     var4='NewName3';
     var10='NewName4';
  end;
  put var2 var5 var4 var10 ;
run;
```

If some of the data for the four columns you want to keep are longer than 200 characters then just update the LENGTH statement.

So let's try a little experiment. First let's make a dummy CSV file.

```
filename example temp;
data _null_;
  file example ;
  input;
  put _infile_;
cards4;
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
;;;;
```

Now let's try running it.  I will modify the INFILE and FILE statements to read from my temp file and write the result to the log.

```
  infile example /* "&infile" */ dsd dlm=',' truncover;
  file log /* "&outfile" */ dsd dlm='|';
```

Here are the resulting rows written.

```
NewName1|NewName2|NewName3|NewName4
2|5|4|10
p|s|r|x
```

Comment: thank you so much for such a detailed explanation! Is there a reason why I could be getting the necessary new variable names, but the contents are all empty?

Comment: Make sure the PUT is after the IF block.  Also make sure the data lines are actually comma delimited. Since the IF block forces the values for the first record it might be that the first line is also being read as empty.  Add this statement to dump the first 5 lines.  `if _n_ <= 5 then putlog _infile_;`

Comment: I tried to fix my script, and I am still getting no results, but the values are delimited by "|" as specified.

Comment: I like to use the `LIST` statement to look at source text files. `data _null_; infile "&infile" obs=5; list; run;`  Perhaps your source file is NOT a csv file? Or your filename is wrong?  If it really is form a mainframe maybe it is in EBCDIC?

Comment: The input is csv, and the path is correct as when I am using the same macro variables in my proc import/export they work.  I would love to run this work in a single script with no intermediate data sets, but still no success with debugging here.

Comment: Totally missing values when the input is not empty is usually sign of a mistake in the INPUT statement or using the wrong variable name in the PUT statement.  In the code I posted the variable names in the SAS program ar VAR1,  VAR2, ... VAR10. Note they have NOTHING to do with the column names in either the source or target delimited files. They are just a way to read the values from one row of the input and write it to the output.